# Don't know how to use the JSON data returned from a web service

Tags: ios, web-services, asp.net-web-api

Apologies if this is not the right forum to ask, I couldn't think of anywhere else to take my question!

I'm trying to get the most recent weather forecast for a location using the following url http://datapoint.metoffice.gov.uk/public/data/val/wxobs/all/json/354379?res=hourly&key=47fbc7c3-dac4-424a-874d-7c8ff5b45b79

I want to get the weather type. The documentation [here](http://www.metoffice.gov.uk/datapoint/product/uk-hourly-site-specific-observations) says that Weather Type would be a code number from `0-30`. However the response from the web service (you can see for yourself following the long hyperlink above) is this:

```
{"SiteRep":{"Wx":{"Param":[{"name":"G","units":"mph","$":"Wind Gust"},{"name":"T","units":"C","$":"Temperature"},{"name":"V","units":"m","$":"Visibility"},{"name":"D","units":"compass","$":"Wind Direction"},{"name":"S","units":"mph","$":"Wind Speed"},{"name":"W","units":"","$":"Weather Type"},{"name":"P","units":"hpa","$":"Pressure"}]},"DV":{"dataDate":"2013-03-15T17:00:00Z","type":"Obs"}}}
```

Now I have no trouble reading that information into an NSDictionary object in my IOS app. But i just can't see which bit contains a code number from 0-30!

If you're wondering if i'm using the right request url, i'm pretty sure i am, i got it from the documentation [here.](http://www.metoffice.gov.uk/datapoint/product/uk-hourly-site-specific-observations/detailed-documentation) (scroll down a little ways.)

I'm just stumped on how to extract the weather type code. I might have gotten myself completely confused and be making the wrong request, their documentation is not very user friendly. As a novice i really need help using this service, but i couldn't find any tutorials with google. Really appreciate anyone who takes the time to look! It would be such a help just to get a second opinion.

Comment: actually the response you are getting is incomplete ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually the response you are getting is incomplete ...complete response is as follows

```
{
"SiteRep": {
    "Wx": {
        "Param": [
            {
                "name": "G",
                "units": "mph",
                "$": "Wind Gust"
            },
            {
                "name": "T",
                "units": "C",
                "$": "Temperature"
            },
            {
                "name": "V",
                "units": "m",
                "$": "Visibility"
            },
            {
                "name": "D",
                "units": "compass",
                "$": "Wind Direction"
            },
            {
                "name": "S",
                "units": "mph",
                "$": "Wind Speed"
            },
            {
                "name": "W",
                "units": "",
                "$": "Weather Type"
            },
            {
                "name": "P",
                "units": "hpa",
                "$": "Pressure"
            }
        ]
    },
    "DV": {
        "dataDate": "2012-12-10T13:00:00Z",
        "type": "Obs",
        "Location": {
            "i": "3772",
            "lat": "51.479",
            "lon": "-0.449",
            "name": "HEATHROW",
            "country": "ENGLAND",
            "continent": "EUROPE",
            "Period": [
                {
                    "type": "Day",
                    "value": "2012-12-09Z",
                    "Rep": [
                        {
                            "D": "W",
                            "P": "1016",
                            "S": "14",
                            "T": "9.0",
                            "V": "40000",
                            "W": "7",
                            "$": "840"
                        },
                        {
                            "D": "W",
                            "P": "1016",
                            "S": "14",
                            "T": "9.0",
                            "V": "40000",
                            "W": "7",
                            "$": "900"
                        },
                        {
                            "D": "W",
                            "P": "1016",
                            "S": "10",
                            "T": "8.6",
                            "V": "45000",
                            "W": "7",
                            "$": "960"
                        },
                        {
                            "D": "W",
                            "P": "1016",
                            "S": "10",
                            "T": "8.2",
                            "V": "40000",
                            "W": "7",
                            "$": "1020"
                        },
                        {
                            "D": "WNW",
                            "P": "1016",
                            "S": "9",
                            "T": "7.9",
                            "V": "40000",
                            "W": "7",
                            "$": "1080"
                        },
                        {
                            "D": "WNW",
                            "P": "1016",
                            "S": "10",
                            "T": "7.1",
                            "V": "30000",
                            "W": "0",
                            "$": "1140"
                        },
                        {
                            "D": "WNW",
                            "P": "1016",
                            "S": "10",
                            "T": "6.5",
                            "V": "28000",
                            "W": "0",
                            "$": "1200"
                        },
                        {
                            "D": "WNW",
                            "P": "1017",
                            "S": "11",
                            "T": "6.2",
                            "V": "27000",
                            "W": "0",
                            "$": "1260"
                        },
                        {
                            "D": "W",
                            "P": "1017",
                            "S": "8",
                            "T": "5.2",
                            "V": "26000",
                            "W": "0",
                            "$": "1320"
                        },
                        {
                            "D": "WNW",
                            "P": "1017",
                            "S": "9",
                            "T": "4.8",
                            "V": "25000",
                            "W": "0",
                            "$": "1380"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "type": "Day",
                    "value": "2012-12-10Z",
                    "Rep": [
                        {
                            "D": "WNW",
                            "P": "1017",
                            "S": "8",
                            "T": "4.6",
                            "V": "23000",
                            "W": "0",
                            "$": "0"
                        },
                        {
                            "D": "WNW",
                            "P": "1017",
                            "S": "8",
                            "T": "4.1",
                            "V": "22000",
                            "W": "0",
                            "$": "60"
                        },
                        {
                            "D": "WNW",
                            "P": "1018",
                            "S": "9",
                            "T": "3.9",
                            "V": "22000",
                            "W": "0",
                            "$": "120"
                        },
                        {
                            "D": "NW",
                            "P": "1018",
                            "S": "9",
                            "T": "3.8",
                            "V": "24000",
                            "W": "0",
                            "$": "180"
                        },
                        {
                            "D": "NW",
                            "P": "1018",
                            "S": "10",
                            "T": "3.3",
                            "V": "26000",
                            "W": "0",
                            "$": "240"
                        },
                        {
                            "D": "NW",
                            "P": "1019",
                            "S": "9",
                            "T": "3.1",
                            "V": "30000",
                            "W": "0",
                            "$": "300"
                        },
                        {
                            "D": "NW",
                            "P": "1019",
                            "S": "9",
                            "T": "2.9",
                            "V": "30000",
                            "W": "0",
                            "$": "360"
                        },
                        {
                            "D": "NW",
                            "P": "1020",
                            "S": "8",
                            "T": "2.8",
                            "V": "28000",
                            "W": "0",
                            "$": "420"
                        },
                        {
                            "D": "NW",
                            "P": "1020",
                            "S": "6",
                            "T": "2.4",
                            "V": "19000",
                            "W": "0",
                            "$": "480"
                        },
                        {
                            "D": "NW",
                            "P": "1021",
                            "S": "8",
                            "T": "2.8",
                            "V": "25000",
                            "W": "1",
                            "$": "540"
                        },
                        {
                            "D": "NNW",
                            "P": "1022",
                            "S": "9",
                            "T": "3.9",
                            "V": "26000",
                            "W": "1",
                            "$": "600"
                        },
                        {
                            "D": "NNW",
                            "P": "1022",
                            "S": "8",
                            "T": "4.7",
                            "V": "25000",
                            "W": "1",
                            "$": "660"
                        },
                        {
                            "D": "N",
                            "P": "1022",
                            "S": "9",
                            "T": "5.5",
                            "V": "27000",
                            "W": "1",
                            "$": "720"
                        },
                        {
                            "D": "N",
                            "P": "1023",
                            "S": "10",
                            "T": "5.6",
                            "V": "30000",
                            "W": "3",
                            "$": "780"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: :O righhht. How did you get that? with the same url request as me?

Comment: with the link you already provided http://www.metoffice.gov.uk/datapoint/product/uk-hourly-site-specific-observations/detailed-documentation